# Finding Hostname of MySQL installed on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, hostname

I am not able to figure out `hostname` of my MySQL database which is installed on AWS T2 micro server.

I can connect via phpmyadmin. And connecting via PHP code as `localhost` works ok too.

However can't find `hostname` or ip which is needed to connect it from service hosted on other server (where `localhost` won't be an option)

Tried running following

```
SELECT variable_value FROM global_variables WHERE variable_name = 'hostname'
```

However the output is `ip-172-31-23-11`. This doesn't work as `hostname` when I try to connect.

Comment: Thanks PraveenS for edit suggested. Could you undo -ve vote now? I am not sure but it may affect getting attention to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The output from `SELECT variable_value FROM global_variables WHERE variable_name = 'hostname'` is showing you the non fully qualified private DNS name.

This should be fine to connect to this instance from the same VPC but if you need to connect from outside of the VPC then instead you should use the public DNS. This, as with the private DNS, is shown in the EC2 dashboard under the instance details (and elsewhere).

As an example:

[image: Example EC2 instance details under the EC2 Dashboard]

You then also need to consider network controls such as VPC ACLs and Security Groups. Make sure the security group of your instance allows access from the originating IP over 3306 (default MySQL port).

You'll also want to check the `bind-address` in /etc/my.cnf to either allow connections specifically from certain addresses as well as localhost/127.0.0.1 or simply remove or comment out the line to allow MySQL to listen to all incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If the application you're trying to connect to the DB with lives on another server, you'll need to get either the public DNS, public IP address, or create an entry in DNS (Route53) that points "database.example.com" into your public IP/DNS name. You can then use one of those as the connection string within the app.

[depending on settings, you may also have to follow some of the instructions here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

you might need to bind mysql to listen on the hosts network interface in order to get outside connectivity.

I suggest using telnet to figure that out. if you can't connect (via the command: "telnet 54.4.54.4 5432" (where 54.4.54.4 is your public ip/DNS/route53 entered hostname) then you need to check your security group as well and make sure port 5432 is open to connections from where you're trying to telnet from.